# Huge delay from ping test with socket.io in nodejs

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am experiencing consistent delay of 25 seconds when running this simple ping test. The server is not logging the ping event but I am assuming it is receiving it because the client is getting a reply. Any ideas on how to fix this?

client

```
    var io = require('socket.io-client')('http://68.12.157.176:3000')
    var ping_time = Date.now();

    function ping(){
      ping_time = Date.now();
      console.log('sending ping...');
      io.emit('ping');
    }
    ping();

    io.on('pong', function (data) {
      ping_time = Date.now() - ping_time;
      console.log("replied in " + ping_time + "ms");
      ping();
    });
```

client log

```
    sending ping...
    replied in 25202ms
    sending ping...
    replied in 25028ms
    sending ping...
    replied in 25029ms
    sending ping...
    replied in 25032ms
    sending ping...
    replied in 25016ms
```

server

```
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var server = require('http').createServer(app);
    var io = require('../..')(server);
    var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

    server.listen(port, function () {
      console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
    });

    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
      console.log('client connected');
      socket.on('ping', function (data) {
        console.log("received ping, sending reply"); //no log shown???
        socket.emit('pong'); //client receives event ~25 seconds after request
      });
    });
```

server log

```
    Server listening at port 3000
    client connected
```

Comment: I think socket.io may be using `ping` and `pong` as message names itself.  Try changing to different message names.

Comment: That solved it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Making my comment into an answer since it solved your problem:

Socket.io is using `ping` and `pong` as message names itself internal to the implementation. Change to different message names.

Comment: I did change the names and worked like a charm! How is this not documented since large amount of developers have been using ping/pong names since 0.9 version. Thanks man, you have no idea the places I looked to fix this!

Comment: @Maziyar - The socket.io doc is pretty minimal - it doesn't cover lots of things.  In my opinion, it's a design mistake that they allow this to be a conflict.

Comment: Hi @jfriend00, I didn't ask the original question so I can't accept it as an answer. But sure it did indeed solve my problem. Hope the user accepts this as an answer.

Comment: @physiii -  Did this answer your question? If so, please indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer. If not, then please explain what you still need help with.